# What is the difference between complete and completeWith in Promise of Scala?

Tags: scala, promise, future

I know they have different interfaces but I am wondering what they differ in essence. What would be different if I pass a Future instead of a Try to the complete function of Promise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot pass a `Future` to `complete`. It will not type check.

The intent of `completeWith` is to complete the promise with the result of given future.
This means it has to wait for the future to complete.